# How do I debug code pushed to my TFS build server?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I have a project that runs, builds, and passes all unit tests locally, but whose unit tests fail on the build server. I am using .NET 4.5, TFS, and VS 2012. Ideally I would like to step through the code that is executing on the server so I can gate on failing unit tests again.

Comment: Do you have remote desktop access to the build server?

Comment: I would ask _why_ the tests are failing on the build server. What is the nature of the failure? Are you certain that the build server is building the exact same code you have locally? Do a Get Latest into a clean workspace, for instance. Are you running the same versions of all the software on the build server as you are locally? If you're desperate enough, you can set up a build controller and agent on your local machine, and try queuing the build to that controller. This would test the same source with the same build against different environment.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I hope to discern why the unit tests are failing by debugging. Several of the unit tests give values out of range on the build server but not locally, and one fails enigmatically with a standard WCF channel fault as I have not implemented the proper custom faults yet. MS Build is the same, MS test, etc. The server had no issues several weeks ago.

Comment: It concerns me that you have "unit tests" which involve WCF. These are what are normally known as "integration tests", since they involve the integration between units. Do all of your tests pass which have no dependency on network or database or anything external?

Comment: @JohnSaunders You are absolutely correct - having unit tests that call WCF methods are integration tests and it is bad form to have them. After doing some digging I found out the following: the default build configuration was changed to call a custom mock framework whose data _wasn't_ being copied over AND one of the unit tests now calls a service that isn't deployed to the build server. In short, you were right. Now, just for my own curiosity, do you know of a way to remotely attach to MSTest remotely with the aim of debugging the unit tests that get called by a build server? Thank you.

Comment: No, I don't know a way. If I had to do this, I would run the unit tests interactively from a Visual Studio installed on the build server and see if I could repro. Beyond that, I don't know. You might have to set up a test agent that runs in interactive mode, or an entire build controller to run in interactive mode, logged in as you, then maybe Debugger.Launch would work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one way,

**Debug directly on the build server**

1. Connect to the build server manually through RDP
2. Navigate to where the build downloaded the source to
3. Open up the solution file(s) in Visual Studio, and in Test Explorer, right-click > Debug Selected Tests

And another way if setting up networking for the VS Remote Debugger isn't a huge pain,

**Remote debug the tests on the build server**

1. Connect to the build server manually through RDP
2. Start the Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor (needs to be downloaded/installed)
3. On your own machine, open up the solution and set up the test project to run using the test runner (e.g. mstest) on the remote machine (see [here](http://lowleveldesign.wordpress.com/2011/01/16/remote-debugging-with-visual-studio-2010/) for screenshots)